# How to search in custom taxonomy's products

Tags: php, wordpress, search, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I created a post type called "product" and custom taxonomy called "product-cat".

I created a general search for products in searchform.php and called in archive-product.php like this:

```php
<div class="search-wrapper">
    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url(site_url('products/')); ?>">
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search products" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="" />
    </form>
</div>
```

also have search.php that I copy every thing from archive-product.php

The question is How can I change the code above that when user in taxonomy products search query only get current taxonomy products and search in that (not all products).

my taxonomy template file is taxonomy-product-cat.php

Also if I need to create new search template file like search-products-cat.php or whatever that I need to do the process please mention it. thanks

Comment: When you say, *when user in taxonomy products search query only get current taxonomy products...* are you saying that the search should limit results to products that have **any** `product-cat` taxonomy term(s)? Or, are you saying that the search results should be limited to products whose terms include **one** specific `product-cat` taxonomy term?

Comment: For example all products are 50. taxonomy "A" have 20 products  I want to modify code above that when the user is in taxonomy "A" page he/she can search only in this 20 products.

Comment: If developing a more complete custom search form with the [get_search_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/) filter hook (e.g. with client-side validation, JavaScript interaction, CSS styling) the [pre_get_search_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_search_form/) action hook will be useful for loading the assets needed.

Answer (score 2):

To address your request: *if I need to create new search template file like search-products-cat.php or whatever...*, note that two common approaches to creating a custom search are:

1. using **searchform.php**, and
2. using the **get_search_form** filter hook (with the pre_get_posts action hook).

The solution below uses the **get_search_form** filter hook. To test it, drop the code into your child theme or plugin and use the `get_search_form()` function at the location where the form should be displayed. The call to `get_search_form()` triggers the **get_search_form** filter to execute.

With the filter hook, you will not need to create multiple template search files. But, you will need to organize your code well with an appropriate design pattern to handle various cases (e.g. different search page designs for different `product-cat` terms). You should be able to easily modify the sample code below for your purposes when using **searchform.php**.

The basic idea demonstrated by the code is to:

1. add custom search filters that are sent to the front-end, and
2. parse the search filters, and add them to WP_Query on the back-end.

You can add custom search filters in many ways. One way is to use `<input type="hidden" />` fields. When the search form is submitted, you can parse the hidden field by its tag name, and add the value to the search query. Sample code is below.

### get_search_form filter hook

```
/**
 * Render a custom search form.
 */
function custom_search_form( $form ) {
    // Post type plural name or the value configured for the `rewrite['slug']` register_post_type option
    $custom_post_type_plural = 'products';
    $custom_taxonomy = 'product-cat';

    $current_post_id = \get_the_ID();

    $related_term_ids = \wp_get_object_terms(
        $current_post_id,
        $custom_taxonomy,
        array(
            'fields' => 'ids'
        )
    );

    // home_url() is used by site visitors.
    // site_url() is the location of the WordPress installation.
    // They are often the same, but not always.
    $home_url = \home_url( $custom_post_type_plural ) . '/';

    if ( \is_singular() ) {
        $related_term_id_list = \esc_attr( implode( ',', $related_term_ids ) );
    } else {
        $related_term_id_list = '';
    }

    $search_query = \esc_attr( \get_search_query() );

    $form = <<<EOHTML
    <div class="search-wrapper">
        <form
            role="search"
            method="GET"
            id="searchform"
            action="$home_url"
        >
            <input type="text" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search products" value="$search_query" />
            <input type="hidden" name="product_cat_term_list" value="$related_term_id_list" />
            <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
        </form>
    </div>
    EOHTML;

    return $form;
}

\add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'custom_search_form' );
```

### pre_get_posts action hook

```
/**
 * Update the query variable 'tax_query' in the WP_Query object.
 * The action hook 'pre_get_posts' allows you to
 * update the query before it is executed.
 *
 * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/#targeting-the-right-query
 *
 */
function target_product_cat_query_with_conditional_tags( $query ) {
    $custom_post_type = 'product';
    $custom_taxonomy = 'product-cat';
    $term_ids_form_field_name = 'product_cat_term_list';

    if ( ! $query->is_admin() &&
        $query->is_search() &&
        isset( $_GET[ $term_ids_form_field_name ] ) &&
        ! empty( $_GET[ $term_ids_form_field_name ] )
    ) {

        // Get the product-cat-term-ids and add them to the tax_query
        $related_term_id_list = $_GET[ $term_ids_form_field_name ];
        $related_term_ids = explode( ',', $related_term_id_list );

        $tax_query = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $custom_taxonomy,
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $related_term_ids
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'target_product_cat_query_with_conditional_tags' );
```

Comment: I don't have any idea what I did wrong but I copy get_search_form filter hook in functions.php. I don't change searchform.php and just get_search_form() same as past in my themplates. in full products lists (archive-product.php) search is doing what it does before it't OK. but for taxonomies when I'm In a taxonomy product list and search something it search in all of the products (search in archive-product.php). Everything same as before except url in taxonomy changes to something like this:
http://localhost/spacevent/products/?s=Aluminum&product_cat_term_list=

Comment: And I don't know how to use pre_get_posts action hook!

Comment: @Alipvd I may have misunderstood your requirements. Could you please correct my interpretation? `product-cat` is a **taxonomy**. `new-and-best-seller` is a **taxonomy term**. Your question asks, *in taxonomy products search query only get current taxonomy products and search in that (not all products).* I interpret this to say, "when a user is viewing a single taxonomy product post (e.g. with current taxonomy term **A**), a search query should only return products that have taxonomy term **A** (and not all products). Is this correct?

Comment: @Alipvd If my interpretation is correct then when an `archive-product.php` page is displayed there is no **current** taxonomy term. An archive-product.php page lists products that could have any *taxonomy term* (even none). A **current** taxonomy term exists when a single post with a product-cat taxonomy term is in view, or a `taxonomy-product-cat-{$term}.php` list page is in view, or if a form field were used for the user to select a product-cat taxonomy term. So, when viewing an `archive-product.php` page, it is normal that search results include products with any product-cat taxonomy term.

Comment: @Alipvd To limit search results to a specific taxonomy term you will need to display the search form on single posts that have product-cat taxonomy terms. (Or, use more form fields, or design `taxonomy-product-cat-{$term}.php` list pages.) Remember, the code I presented gives you a basic idea of how to create a custom search. The idea can easily be used with **searchform.php**. Once you understand what the code is doing you will be able to update it for your use case. If you need further help, let me know.

Comment: @Alipvd In response to your statement: *I don't know how to use pre_get_posts action hook!*, I provided the WordPress link. The docs say: *Fires before the search form is retrieved, at the start of get_search_form().* You configure a callback for the hook like this: `add_action( 'pre_get_search_form', 'YOUR-CALLBACK-FUNCTION' );`. When you call the **get_search_form()** function, WordPress triggers YOUR-CALLBACK-FUNCTION to be called before get_search_form() is executed. This means you can use YOUR-CALLBACK-FUNCTION to load JavaScript and CSS files before your search form is rendered.

Comment: @Alipvd To be honest, there is a lot more work needed to get a custom search form working well. For example, by default the Search Results page does not display the search form. If you want users to be able to make another search after receiving results you might have to use the [Site Editor](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/site-editor/) to edit the Search Results block in a Template. Doing this requires having either a shortcode or block configured to render the custom search form. It might be worth it to think about using a plugin rather than developing this yourself.