# Search custom taxonomy titles and not the posts themselves

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called 'rejectedpayments' and I have a custom taxonomy called 'rejpayments-category' which is assigned to this CPT. I then have an archive template that displays all the taxonomy term titles only (NOT the actual posts) then I can click the taxonomy term title to see all posts that are in that taxonomy. There is a search field on this page and this is what I'm struggling with. The search just searches by custom post type so it searches every post in the 'rejectedpayments' CPT but I want it to only search the actual term titles.

So if I have:

Term 1

- Post 1
- Post 2

Term 2

- Post 1
- Post 2

Term 3

- Post 1
- Post 2

Currently if I search for 'Post' there are obviously 6 posts with this in the title so they come up (it doesn't search the term title at all) so the titles, Term 1, Term 2 and Term 3 are what I want to search only.

The only filter on the form is obviously the CPT name but I wouldn't have a clue how to add an additional filter so it also adds a parameter of search term name only.

```
<form role="search" action="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>" method="get" id="searchform">
    <div class="row form-wrap">
        <div class="col-md-10 padding-none">
            <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search all rejected payments"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="rejectedpayments" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 padding-none">
            <input type="submit" alt="Search" value="Search" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

***My current archive page that lists all Term names only within the specific custom post type***

```
<?php $wcatTerms = get_terms('rejpayments-category', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' =>0)); 
  foreach($wcatTerms as $wcatTerm) : 
?>
<div class="results-table">
  <div class="row info-tables">
    <div class="col-md-6">   
      <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $wcatTerm->slug, $wcatTerm->taxonomy ); ?>"><?php echo $wcatTerm->name; ?></a>
      <?php
        $wsubargs = array(
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'show_option_none' => '',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'parent' => $wcatTerm->term_id,
        'taxonomy' => 'rejpayments-category'
         );
           $wsubcats = get_categories($wsubargs);
           foreach ($wsubcats as $wsc):
          ?>
          <p><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $wsc->slug, $wsc->taxonomy );?>"><?php echo $wsc->name;?></a></p>
          <?php
            endforeach;
          ?>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6"> 
           LINK
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <?php 
     endforeach; 
  ?>
```

When using @kofeigen' answer, I get the following error:

*Notice: Function wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly. The query argument of wpdb::prepare() must have a placeholder. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.9.0.) in /var/www/vhosts/domainnamehere/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '...' (T_ELLIPSIS) in /var/www/vhosts/domainnamehere/wp-content/themes/themename/cat-rejected-payments.php on line 55*

Comment: Hi @jfar_2020. Please see my answer to this question: [How to search in custom taxonomy's products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75962683). Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

Comment: Still no luck sadly, I'm not sure if your code does what I need but I thought Id try it anyway to start with then work from there. I added the code from get_search_form_filter_hook into functions and amended my archive template to pull in the search form via get_search_form but it still just searches the actualk posts, not the taxonomy titles themselves. Is pre_get_posts action hook required too or is that an alternative method? I did add that in too for testing and that didnt seem to have any affect.

Comment: Similar to OP on that post you linked to (I think) I am not in a taxonomy term at this stage, this is on an archive page so it lists all terms under the taxonomy 'rejectedpayments' It is on here I want to search all the terms only and not the actual posts within those terms.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. (I am still confused). Are you saying that you want a search form on the archive-{custom_post_type} page where the results page lists taxonomy terms and not post titles? Then, on the results page, each result is a link that targets another results page showing post titles with the selected taxonomy term?

Comment: @kofeigen It is difficult to explain! I have updated the question with what I have on my archive page, this lists the terms only (so in my. example, it lists Term 1, Term 2 and Term 3. No posts, just the term names themselves as links. Clicking a link will take me to a page that lists all the posts assigned to that term name but on this same archive page is a search form, I want that search form to search the term names only so if I searched for 'Term' there would be 3 results (as each of my terms in the example are actually called 'Term'. The search is to find terms, not posts.

Comment: So when doing a search, it wants to search all term titles only, not post titles or content.

Comment: @kofeigen Reading your last question, yes that is exactly right. To put it into context, each term is a persons name and that person will have multiple posts related to them so this is the best way I could see of doing it. Therefore the archive I have just lists all the people's names so when I search on this archive, it just wants to search the people's names only so that a user can quickly find a particular oerson then go in and see all the posts related to them. I have it all working great other than this search.

Comment: Once searched, the results will look exactly the same as the main archive ie. just a list of names related to that search query. All these names are links which will then go to a page showing all posts related to that name.

Answer (score 0):

The following updates to the archive page could be used to generate the desired search results.

### Submit the form to the archive page

The archive page could submit the form to itself. The form `action` attribute could be changed as follows:

```
<?php

    ...

    global $wp;
    $current_url = home_url( add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request ) );?>

    ...

    <form role="search" action="$current_url" method="get" id="searchform">
```

### Add a name attribute to the submit button

```
<input name="submittedForm" type="submit" alt="Search" value="Search" />
```

### Get an unfiltered terms list (default) or a terms list filtered by the search form

```
/**
 * Untested code.
 * You may wish to change the ORDER BY clause.
 * 
 * @param string $searchKey Search key submitted from the search form.
 * 
 * @return object[] $wcatTerms Array of taxonomy term objects.
 */
function get_filtered_taxonomy_terms( $searchKey ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $custom_taxonomy = 'CUSTOM_TAXONOMY_NAME';

    $table_prefix = $wpdb->prefix;

    $escaped_search_key = $wpdb->esc_like( $searchKey );

    $sql  = "";
    $sql .= "SELECT T.term_id, T.slug, T.name, TT.term_taxonomy_id, TT.description, TT.parent, TT.count";
    $sql .= " FROM {$table_prefix}terms T";
    $sql .= " JOIN {$table_prefix}term_taxonomy TT ON ( TT.term_id = T.term_id )";
    $sql .= " WHERE TT.taxonomy = '${custom_taxonomy}'";
    $sql .= " AND T.name LIKE '%" . $escaped_search_key . "%'";
    $sql .= " ORDER BY T.name ASC";
    $sql .= ";";

    $wcatTerms = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, 'OBJECT' );

    return $wcatTerms;
}


if ( isset( $_GET ) && isset( $_GET['submittedForm'] ) ) {
    // Search form submitted.
    // Find array of all terms (parents and children)
    // with term name partially matching the search key.
    $wcatTerms = get_filtered_taxonomy_terms( $_GET['s'] );

    ...

} else {
    // Default terms list.
    $wcatTerms = get_terms('rejpayments-category', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' =>0));

    ...

}
```

### Render results

With hierarchical terms, different approaches can be used to render the list depending on maximum depth, etc. The WordPress [Walker class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker/) could be extended and used to render the list. An example of such an extension is the WordPress [Walker_Nav_Menu class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/).

Comment: Thanks for this, for the 'Get an unfiltered terms list' code would that go in functions.php or within the archive template along with the search form? I have tried both and get a critical error but at least if I know what the answer to that is, I can go from there to work out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @jfar_2020 I just made a small update to my answer to indicate that all changes are to be made to the archive page. This assumes the code for the form and list rendering are all in the same file, or imported into the same file. If errors show up, perhaps you can post it here, and I could take a look.

Comment: I enabled debug and have updated the answer with the error I get. I basically wrapped your code here in php tags and inserted it just after the header call above everything else.

Comment: @jfar_2020 I tested my original `get_filtered_taxonomy_terms` function and it works. But, I updated my answer with an alternative that removes the call to `wpdb->prepare()`. I tested this alternative, and it also works. Please try this and let me know the outcome. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck. the prepare message is still there (in fact its there with debug enabled even without your code so clearly thats a different issue) but it doesnt like the 2 lots of '...'. The full message is

Comment: Notice: Function wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly. The query argument of wpdb::prepare() must have a placeholder. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.9.0.) in /var/www/vhosts/domainname/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '...' (T_ELLIPSIS) in /var/www/vhosts/domainname/wp-content/themes/themename/cat-rejected-payments.php on line 53

Comment: If I remove the '...' it still doesn't work of course but it also doesn't load any results on the same page, it shows the results on /index.php. I mean for the value of my time, I'd much rather hire you to fix for me, is that a possibility at all?

Comment: @jfar_2020 The "..." (ellipsis) in my code should not have been copied into your PHP. The ellipsis means that I intentionally left out code that you are to fill in yourself depending on how you want to render the list. You can think of it like saying, "*to be continued...*" This is why I suggested the WordPress Walker class. Thank you for the offer of hiring me. Do you have a repository of your code available somewhere that would allow me to submit requested changes? I might be able to offer a more complete solution for you without hiring. Thanks.

Comment: Course, Im not thinking here! Its on github but as a personal repository. If you have an account on there can you let me know your username and I'll invite you?

Comment: @jfar_2020 Sure. My username there is the same as here.

Comment: Great, I've added you now. That's the archive template in there. I kept it private as it's work related and don't want all our competitors seeing our code :) Hope you understand.

Comment: @jfar_2020 Thanks. I'll send a pull request when finished.